# Chrome lags on page wth large images

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-applications, lag

I have a webapplication with a page, which contains a few 'large' images (multiple images between 1MB-8MB)

On Chrome (v49), this page is lagging extremely, while Internet Explorer (v11) and Firefox (v45) are handling it perfectly without any lag.

Even Chrome does lag with 2 images of only 1,5MB!

How can i fix this without making the images smaller in size? And is this a Chrome Bug? I can't find alot on Google exept users are having scroll lag because of 'large' images.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem. Did you find any solution to it?

Comment: No, i just did'nt display it. I added a button and users can open the images 1 by 1 if they want to see it instead of displaying them all